# Can PeerJS be connected to two or more different applications?

Tags: javascript, peerjs

Is it possible to connect a few unrelated applications with different hostname to connect to the same PeerJS' channel.

For example: channel can be where the channel can connect with app1.example.com, app2.example.com, app3.example.com with three different hostname, codebase, but share same application channel.

The idea is to do something like notifications between apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Peerjs clients connect to a server to actually connect. You can use the default server that peerjs uses (omit the part after the id), or host your own server.

On client:

```js
peer = new Peer(id,
     {
      host: "mydomain.com",
      port: 9000,
      path: "/",
    })
```